How to use the Emacs Lisp implementations of several UNIX commands in emacs (outside of eshell)
I am curious, is it possiblie to use the Emacs Lisp implementations of UNIX commands out side of eshell?
For example, can I point grep (or consult-grep) to eshell/grep (instead of the external program)? How would I do so?
I am interested in this because it makes Emacs (partially) more self sufficient. And more tools/commands might run OOTB without additional installations.
Note: I am aware of other solutions getting UNIX tools under Windows (e.g. https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports or with a shell like Cygwin or Git Bash).
I am looking forward for your input.
Best
Jonas

Do you want to run elisp programs from your regular shell outside of Emacs, or do you mean you want (for example) M-x grep inside Emacs to use eshell/grep ?

The latter, and and possibly also point consult-grep towards eshell/grep as well...

I don't know anything about consult-grep.  All I can suggest is that you look at the source and see what it actually does...

Does M-x eshell-command RET grep ... answer your question?

Hm, I didn't know about that command, and will look into it ... but atm this seems only tangentially related to my question.

If it's only tangential, then I guess you're asking "can arbitrary command based on external process be told to use arbitrary elisp function instead?", and the answer to that would be... maybe? it depends... on a case-by-case basis... depending on how that particular command was implemented.

E.g. M-x grep uses compilation-start which calls start-file-process-shell-command and so you can't trivially configure it to use the eshell/grep function.  Maybe in other cases you can; but for any command you're interested in, you'd need to look at the specific implementation of that command...

Although if the eshell output is compatible with that of the standard command, then we can get back to my earlier question "Do you want to run elisp programs from your regular shell outside of Emacs?" and set up external shell commands to invoke an emacs batch process running the eshell command, and then tell the likes of M-x grep to use that as the external grep-program.  Provided that the output is what's required, and all of the necessary command-line options are handled, there's no reason that couldn't work.
